# Display text in DataGridView when there are no rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As shown in the screenshot below, I want to display text in DataGridView when there are no rows (empty dataGridView). I want to display text something like

- No data to display

Does anyone know how to implement this behavior?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most re-usable way is to subclass DataGridView, add an EmptyResultText property and catch the Paint event. From there you can add text to the center of the grid like so:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utility {
    public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView {

        public string EmptyResultText { get; set; }

        public MyDataGridView() {
            this.Paint += MyDataGridView_Paint;
        }

        private void MyDataGridView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmptyResultText)) {
                if (this.Rows.Count == 0) {
                    using (var gfx = e.Graphics) {
                        gfx.DrawString(this.EmptyResultText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                            new PointF((this.Width - this.Font.Size * EmptyResultText.Length) / 2, this.Height / 2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
    var myGrid = new MyDataGridView();
    myGrid.EmptyResultText = "No Result Dude";
    myGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    myGrid.DataSource = new List<string>();
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(myGrid);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Paint() for doing this work.You should check if grid has not any record eith this line `sender.Rows.Count` So Draw a String .

```
private void grd_Paint ( object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView sender= ( DataGridView )sender;

    if ( sender.Rows.Count == 0 ) 
    {
        using ( Graphics g= e.Graphics )
        {
            g.FillRectangle ( Brushes.White, new Rectangle ( new Point (), new Size ( sender.Width, 25 ) ) );
            g.DrawString ( "No data to display", new Font ( "Arial", 12 ), Brushes.Red, new PointF ( 3, 3 ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Shahrooz Jafari . it worked but the "No data" text is located on the top of the Datagridview ( on the column header ) no in the middle of the datagridview. do you know how can I modify the code so the text can be in the middle? thank you